# C++11 constexpr function compiler error with ternary conditional operator (?:)

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, ternary-operator, constexpr

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned int N, unsigned int P=0>
constexpr unsigned int Log2() {
    return (N <= 1) ? P : Log2<N/2,P+1>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Log2(8) = " << Log2<8>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling with `gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`, I get the following error:

```
log2.cpp: In function ‘constexpr unsigned int Log2() [with unsigned int N = 0u, unsigned int P = 1023u]’:
log2.cpp:5:38: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 1024 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum) instantiating ‘constexpr unsigned int Log2() [with unsigned int N = 0u, unsigned int P = 1024u]’
log2.cpp:5:38:   recursively instantiated from ‘constexpr unsigned int Log2() [with unsigned int N = 4u, unsigned int P = 1u]’
log2.cpp:5:38:   instantiated from ‘constexpr unsigned int Log2() [with unsigned int N = 8u, unsigned int P = 0u]’
log2.cpp:10:37:   instantiated from here
```

Comment: Why don't you have a specialisation to terminate the recursion?

Comment: @doctorlove That wouldn't actually help; it would require partial specialization of a function.

Comment: Isn't (N<=1) ? P a termination criterion?

Comment: @Danvil: Yes, but the conditional operator works at runtime, meaning both branches need to be evaluated.

Comment: @Xeo: If it would be evaluated at runtime, then why should it actually *call* the function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Constexpr doesn't work that way.

Simply put, constexpr functions must be available as runtime functions too. Imagine you took the constexpr off the function. Then think about why it cannot possibly work.

The reason is that the compiler has to instantiate the body of the function completely; it cannot decide based on the condition in the `?:` not to instantiate one side. So it always has to instantiate the recursive call, leading to infinite recursion.

In any case, you're using constexpr wrong. You're using the old template metaprogramming calculation technique (passing stuff as template parameters) when constexpr was intended to replace this. Just use normal parameters.

```
constexpr unsigned Log2(unsigned n, unsigned p = 0) {
    return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
}

std::cout << "Log2(8) = " << Log2(8) << std::endl;
```

**Edit:** I'll try to elaborate on how this works.

When the compiler encounters your code, it parses the template function and stores it in template form. (How this works differs between compilers.) So far, all is fine.

Next, in `main`, the compiler sees the call `Log2<8>()`. It sees that it has to instantiate the template, so it goes ahead and does exactly that: it instantiates `Log2<8, 0>`. The body of the function template is this:

```
return (N <= 1) ? P : Log2<N/2,P+1>();
```

OK, the compiler sees this, but it doesn't try to evaluate it. Why would it? It's currently instantiating a template, not calculating a value. It just substitutes the values supplied:

```
return (8 <= 1) ? 0 : Log2<8/2,0+1>();
```

Huh, there's another template instantiation here. It doesn't matter that it's in a conditional expression, or that the left hand side could be known. Template instantiation must be complete. So it goes ahead and calculates the values for the new instantiation and then instantiates `Log2<4, 1>`:

```
return (4 <= 1) ? 1 : Log2<4/2,1+1>();
```

And the game begins again. There's a template instantiation in there, and it's `Log2<2, 2>`:

```
return (2 <= 1) ? 2 : Log2<2/2,2+1>();
```

And again, `Log2<1,3>()`:

```
return (1 <= 1) ? 3 : Log2<1/2,3+1>();
```

Did I mention that the compiler doesn't care about the semantic meaning of this stuff? It's just yet another template to instantiate: `Log2<0,4>`:

```
return (0 <= 1) ? 4 : Log2<0/2,4+1>();
```

And then `Log2<0,5>`:

```
return (0 <= 1) ? 5 : Log2<0/2,5+1>();
```

And so on, and so on. At some point the compiler realizes that it never stops, and gives up. But at no point does it say, "Wait, the condition of that ternary operator is false, I don't need to instantiate the right-hand side." That's because the C++ standard doesn't allow it to. The function body must be instantiated completely.

Now look at my solution. There's no template. There's just a function. The compiler sees it and goes, "Hey, here's a function. Awesome, let me put in a call to that function here." And then at some point (it might be immediately, it might be a lot later, depending on the compiler), it might (but is not forced to, in this case) say, "Hey, wait, this function is `constexpr` and I know the parameter values, let me evaluate that." Now it goes ahead and evaluates `Log2(8, 0)`. Remember the body:

```
return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
```

"OK", the compiler says, "I just want to know what this function returns. Let's see, `8 <= 1` is false, so look at the right side. `Log2(4, 1)`, huh? Let me look at that. OK, `4 <= 1` is also false, so it must be `Log2(2, 2)`. What's that, `2 <= 1`? Also false, so it's `Log2(1, 3)`. Hey, `1 <= 1` is true, so let me take that `3` and return it. All the way up the call stack."

So it comes up with the answer 3. It doesn't go into endless recursion because it's evaluating the function with full knowledge of values and semantics, not just stupidly building up ASTs.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I do not understand this limitation. When the left part of ?: is true why the evaluation of the right part? It will never be used...

Comment: Thanks, but I do not understand why this works and the original code does not. You are using the ?: the same way. Why is the compiler not evaluating the right expression here?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! So for templates the compiler does evaluate the right side of ?: but for constexpr it does not -- even if the constexpr is evaluated at compile time. This looks somehow arbitrary to me ...

Comment: No, no, no. For templates, there **is no evaluation**. There's *instantiation*, which always "looks" at everything. Only when instantiation is finished does evaluation take place. With constexpr, there's no instantiation, which is why this works.

Comment: The bottom line is, template metaprogramming is hard (it requires you to understand how template instantiation works in detail), which is why constexpr was invented. Constexpr is easy (especially in C++14, where most of its restrictions are lifted), so use it instead. It only needs you to understand how execution works, which every C++ programmer has to understand anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As others already said: The compiler won't evaluate a conditional expression such as `if`/`else` or a ternary operator `?:`. However, there is still a way to make this conditional expression compile time:

```
#include <cstddef>     // size_t is shorter than unsigned int, it's a matter of taste in this case
#include <iostream>    // to show our results
#include <type_traits> // needed for the mighty std::enable_if

template<size_t N, size_t P = 0>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<(N <= 1), size_t>::type Log2()
{
   return P;
}

template<size_t N, size_t P = 0>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<!(N <= 1), size_t>::type Log2()
{
   return Log2<N / 2, P + 1>();
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << Log2<1>() << "\n";
   std::cout << Log2<2>() << "\n";
   std::cout << Log2<4>() << "\n";
   std::cout << Log2<8>() << "\n";
   std::cout << Log2<16>() << "\n";
}
```

What this does is rather obvious: If `N <= 1`, the first branch should be evaluated, thus `Log2<0, P>()` and `Log2<1, P>()` should evaluate to `P`. If `N <= 1`, the upper method is enabled as this function header is valid. For everything else, i.e. `N >= 2` or `!(N <= 1)`, we need to recurse, which is done by the second method.